# Can I say one point five hours?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I don't mean "one and a half hours", but I mean "one point five hours" when I talk about duration like when I say

> I've been here for **one point five hours**.
>
> My kids spend like **one point five hours** to finish there lunch.

Comment: I'm a little confused by _I don't mean "one and half hours", but I mean "one point five hours"_. "One and half hours" is ungrammatical but sounds close to "one and a half hours" which means 1.5 hours. Did you think it means something else or intend something else?

Comment: @TypeIA I did not know that I can ever say one point five hours, I know that I can write it but not sure whether I can say it, and yes I mean one and a half hours

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've been here for one point five hours.

Sure, you can say this, but people will look at you funny and wonder if you're a mad scientist! It's grammatically correct and would be understood, but the far more natural thing to say is:

> I've been here for an hour and a half.

Or, less naturally and more stiff/formal:

> I've been here for one and a half hours.

Also, you made a very common (even for native speakers) spelling mistake:

> ... to finish **their** lunch (instead of *there*)

Comment: You can drop the word "like" without changing the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The only time when one might write or say 1.5 hours is when describing a mathematical calculation where it is necessary to measure time in hours. For example when calculating speed in kilometres per hour. I have never heard it used in everyday speech.
It means one and a half hours.

Comment: The (online) time sheet system I have to use measures time in decimal hours (to one place). That is one reason I don't like it.

Comment: That does seem pretty inconvenient. So if you work 6 hours and 45 mins you have to round that to 6.8 hours?

Comment: that's right. It has the times in drop-down menus with the usual format (in 6 minute increments, so 9:00, 9:06, etc), but the time worked is presented in decimal hours. I've got used to it, but it is still a bit of a pest.